# Python takes binary input and turns it into random numbers

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, binary

I am trying to make a mini 8-bit binary display using Pimoroni Blinkt! on Raspberry Pi, and when I input a binary number, it outputs random numbers: [I enter 00010011 and it outputs 4105](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQuia.png), when it should output `00010011`

My code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import blinkt
import time

blinkt.set_clear_on_exit(False)
blinkt.set_brightness(0.1)

current_pos_bin = 0
#minute = '00010011'
binNum = input('Binary number: ')
listBin = list(str(binNum))
print(binNum)
print(listBin)

for i in listBin:
        if i == '0':
                blinkt.set_pixel(current_pos_bin, 0, 0, 0)
                blinkt.show()
        elif i == '1':
                blinkt.set_pixel(current_pos_bin, 255, 255, 255)
                blinkt.show()
        else:
                print('error')
        print(current_pos_bin)
        current_pos_bin += 1
        #time.sleep(1)
blinkt.show()
```

Comment: Are you using Python2 by any chance? Nvm, I had a second think about it and you're most likely not.

Comment: Just put a proper shebang as the first line, i.e. `#!/usr/bin/python3` and make the script executable with `chmod +x YourScript.py` then you can run it with `./YourScript.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using python 3.8. I tried your code without using the blink library.
It worked fine for me. Maybe take a closer look in the blink documentation or check your python version.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why the two `print()` outputs `4105` tho?

Comment: I've worked out it only works with python3, so I need to work out how to set that as default...

Comment: I am glad that i could help.